# Facebook auth setup on local

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, apache, oauth

I have a site I work with locally using openserver (site on Laravel 5.5 framework). I use Apache-PHP-7.2. I want to make auth with Facebook using Laravel-Socialite. I set `http://localhost/` as Facebook Site URL. My routes:

```
Route::get('login/facebook', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('login/facebook/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

services.php:

```
'redirect' => 'http://mysite/login/facebook/callback'
```

When I try to go `http://mysite/login/faceboook`, I get an error:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.
>   I see my non-authorized requests on developers panel.

My settings (I can't embeded img yet):

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwdVj.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1co5.png

App key is correct, secret too.

Comment: You haven't supplied a valid oauth redirect uri in the second image

Comment: @btl I get access to my site as `http://mysite`. I can't add this url as redirect on Facebook. I can add `http://localhost`, but than I have to edit my `hosts` file? Because of different domain (make like `http://localhost/mysite`).

Answer (score 0):

You should add your domain here and than save, should work. 
[image]

Comment: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings. I use only `http://mysite` to get my site (without `.local`). Maybe I have to change my domain?